# Table layout with inner div

Tags: css

I would like to have a simple table layout, but my HTML contains additional DIV between row and cells:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80px;
}

ul {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.inter {
  /* display: ??? */
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>
      Head 1
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
      Head 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class='row'>
      <div class='inter'>
        <!-- this div spoils the layout -->
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 11
        </div>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 12
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class='row'>
      <div class='inter'>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 21
        </div>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 22
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The result would be perfect, if there is no 'div.inter'. Any idea how to make proper layout table having this additional div?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Olin9/d7kvgweg/

Comment: I have to ask. Does this "table" contain data? If so, why aren't you using `<table>`?

Comment: The HTML structure is produced by JS libraries. So - I would like to have a pure CSS solution.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The HTML you show defines that structure. A `<table>` element defines a different structure. If you are using tabular data, why aren't you using `<table>`? (Though my question is, are you using tabular data?) A table element would make this far easier if it's appropriate.

Comment: I am using HTML produced in the way I described, and I'm wondering, if it's possible to arrange it in proper way, using only CSS

Answer (score 0):

The most perfect here would be to use `display: contents` which mean that elements will be replaced by their children. Unfortunately this is supported only by Firefox. Demo:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80px;
}

ul {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.inter {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>
      Head 1
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
      Head 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class='row'>
      <div class='inter'>
        <!-- this div spoils the layout -->
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 11
        </div>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 12
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class='row'>
      <div class='inter'>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 21
        </div>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 22
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But to work in all browsers I suggest you to use table nesting here if you need to preserve your markup. For this particular example to work specify for `.row` `display: table`.

```css
.row {
  display: table;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80px;
}

ul {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.inter {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>
      Head 1
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
      Head 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class='row'>
      <div class='inter'>
        <!-- this div spoils the layout -->
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 11
        </div>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 12
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class='row'>
      <div class='inter'>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 21
        </div>
        <div class='cell'>
          Cell 22
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vadim, but this is not what I'm looking for. The solution must be cross-browser, so not the first one. The second solution produces several tables, so it's definitely not what is needed (each table may have different column width).

Comment: I suppose that issue is not in this div but in `ul` and `li` blocks. Mable you'd better remove `ul` and `li` from your table?

Comment: I do not think it is connected with `ul` and `li` tags. Replacing them with `div`'s does not change anything. Moreover, the HTML document structure is the result of JS libraries, so I would like not to change them - just have pure CSS solution...

Comment: @OlgierdDzięcielski How about JavaScript solution that will resolve your issue?

Comment: JS solution is quite obvious, so if there is no pure CSS solution, I will be forced to go into it

Comment: @OlgierdDzięcielski Well, maybe CSS exists, but it won't be "pure", it will be "hacky". Your layout here is abnormal for table.